# Relays: What is High Contact Stability?

Tags: rf, relay, stability, dielectric

This [TE RF relay datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/418/ENG_SS_108-98001_S%5B1%5D-1210543.pdf) shows the component coming in three varieties:

- High Dielectric
- High Contact Stability
- High Current

So high-current is obvious (right?), and (correct me if I'm wrong) high dielectric is for higher voltages...

**But what does contact stability mean?**

Comment: I had to look it up but it appears related to quality of the signal passing through.

Comment: @DKNguyen, reference?  More detail, or an answer?

Comment: I'm only finding brief mentions of it implying this rather than concrete. I'm googling "relay contact stability".

Comment: Here is something more substantial: https://www.ni.com/en-ca/innovations/white-papers/08/armature-relay-contact-stability.html#section-566115566

Comment: @DKNguyen, I googled relay contact stability and found that same article.  It uses the word "stability" only in the title and, as you found, that article didn't really pin down the answer.  I'm speculating that it has to do with contact breakdown over time, but of course thats just speculation

Comment: That's what I'm getting too. Just general degradation of the contact by any and all means whether corrosion, oxidation, pitting, residue deposits, burning, wet switching, whatever. I think it's referring to stability of the contact resistance.

Comment: Panasonic has a document with a lot of information on relays. Worth a look.
https://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/pew/cz/downloads/technical_information_relay_en.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a signal relay datasheet with additional data for RF applications.

High dielectric and surge capability relates to high voltage breakdown between open contacts and between coil and contacts.

Contact stability relates to mechanical shock and vibration resistance.